# How to store/query co-ordiantes for calculating the distance between in meters?

Tags: c#, spatial, nettopologysuite

I am storing co-ordinates in my database like this

```
var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);

var point = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate(
    command.GeoCoordinate!.Longitude,
    command.GeoCoordinate!.Latitude));
```

I then need to query the db for any points within a certain distance of some co-ordinate, so I pass in an expression like this

```
x => x.Location.Distance(inputPoint) < distance
```

However, the distance returned just uses a normal pythagarus calculation, giving me a result in degrees rather than meters or miles.

I can manually calculate the distance in meters using haversine formula, but passing that in to my expression reults in a linq error:

> The LINQ expression  could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to ..

How can I store/query this data such that I can pass a filter to ef core and get back a list of results within the given distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to work with EPSG:4326 (Lat/lon coordinate pairs, rather than projected coordinates like [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system))?

If you could switch to UTM coordinates you would have meters directly in the database and wouldn't need to worry about conversion.

Comment: In the end I converted the lat/lng to EPSG:27700 (I only need UK/Ireland locations) before storing in the database and it seems to work fine